# Check if a char array is built of 2 identical ones

Tags: c++, char

Which of the following expressions return true only if the character array s, formed out of exactly 10 characters, is obtained by concatenating 2 identical array strings?

```
a) strcmp(s, s+5) == 0

b) s==strstr(s, s+5)

c) s==s+5

d) strcmp(s, strcat(s, s+5))==0
```

I have checked each of the answers and figured out b is actually the right one. For a) I think it checks character by character until the NULL character in s+5 is reached. Therefore it returns 1 (s>s+5). Correct me if this is wrong.

But I can't understand what happens "behind the scene" in c and d. What's compared in s==s+5? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use these functions in C++.

Comment: I don't use them. It's just an exercise from a book

Comment: Then you should get a better book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `s` is guaranteed to be of exactly 10 characters:

```
strncmp(s, s+5, 5) == 0
```

As for your original candidates:

```
a) strcmp(s, s+5) == 0
```

`s` is a string of 10 characters and `s+5` is a string of 5 characters, so this will always evaluate to false.

```
b) s==strstr(s, s+5)
```

This actually does what your want.  If the first half and second half of the string are identical, then searching the second half as a sub-string in the entire string will return `s` as the first occurrence.  If they are not identical, then whatever it returns will not be `s`.

```
c) s==s+5
```

This simply compares two different character pointers and will always evaluate to false.

```
d) strcmp(s, strcat(s, s+5))==0
```

The call to `strcat()` will cause disaster since it's trying to append the string `s+5` to the end of `s`.  It copies the characters starting from `s+5` to the end of `s` which in turn lengthens the string `s+5` itself, so this will never end.

Comment: I've got to select one from the list

Comment: Then choose `b)`.  It does what you want, though not in an obvious way.

Comment: @user3285580: Even if no correct answer is in the list?